# Lite version of app then require registration

Tags: xcode

I have an app that is going to be pretty pricey and is a specialized to the wedding industry. My goal is to try and limit illegal distribution. I thought about offering it for free but with a big watermark over it. The user would have to register and pay in order to remove it. Two questions. Is this possible? And, if so, I would need to provide the user an "Unlock Code" specific to the device serial number so that one serial won't work on another device because it's a formula based serial that uses the serial number of the device. I would generate this unlock code manually. I am just wondering if this seems possible. Keep in mind, this app isn't  for a large group of people. It's a specific group so I am not concerned with making it hard for users.

Comment: Is this a Mac app? Or an iOS app?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Apple would allow such an app to go on sale on the App Store. This is because if you offer a free version you're not allowed to significantly cripple its functionality, which adding a big watermark would do. Apple would also want the unlocking of the app to be done via an In-App Purchase rather than some proprietary scheme.